# How to handle the chrome notification in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

While I am trying to automate the makemytrip website it shows some notification message from google. I don't know how to handle that notification. It shows `NosuchElementException` while using the web element id from html source code.

[image]

Comment: can you shear the HTML?

Comment: `NosuchElementException` is because it's in an iFrame... see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an iFrame hence the `NosuchElement exception`.

You need to `switchTo().frame` in your case it should look like this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("notification-frame-~5586290a");
```

After switching into the `iframe` you can click the buttons there...

In your case, if you want to close it do something like:

```
driver.FindElementsByXPath('//*[@class="wewidgeticon we_close icon-large"]').click()
```

If you do not close it but want to go back to the default frame just use:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope this helps you!